# Delete End of File

Tags: c, winapi

For instance if I called WriteFile to the end of a file, and later I wanted to delete the written bytes, how could I do this? Do I have to read the file's contents into a buffer, re-create the file, and write the desired bytes, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365542%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to the file position you want to truncate from (if you're not already there), then call the aptly-named [SetEndOfFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365531%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

On Posix complient systems (Unix, Linux and others (Windows 7 has the Posix layer again))

```
int truncate(const char *path, off_t length); 
int ftruncate(int fildes, off_t length);
```

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/truncate.html

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ftruncate.html